# ScrollView não rola em tela 320x240

Tags: android, xamarin, xaml

Tenho uma página xaml com um ScrollView e um ListView que funcionam normalmente em smartphones populares.
O problema é que a barra de rolagem não funciona no aparelho Samsung Pocket Duos, que tem uma tela de 320x240 e 2.8". Como muitas pessoas ainda usam este aparelho, limitar o app para ele não é uma opção. 
Alguma idéia?

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" ><!--VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"-->

        <StackLayout Padding="12,8,8,0" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
            <Label x:Name="txtPrefixoTitulo" Text="Vagas para" FontSize="12" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="0.54" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  Margin="0"/>
            <Label x:Name="txtFuncaoCidade" Text="" FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="0.54" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Margin="0" />
        </StackLayout>

        <Label Font="Bold,20" x:Name="labelLoader" TextColor="#4a90e2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible="False" Text="Carregando vagas, por favor aguarde." />
        <ActivityIndicator Color="#4a90e2" IsRunning="false" x:Name="loader" IsVisible="false"/>

        <ScrollView Padding="8, 0, 8, 0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="scroll">
            <ListView x:Name="lstView"  HasUnevenRows="true" VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="#f4f4f4" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemAppearing="ItemAppearing">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate><!--SelectedItem="teste"-->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell AutomationId="viewCellVaga">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="{Binding CorFundo}" Padding="16, 12, 16, 20" VerticalOptions="Fill"  Spacing="0" Margin="0, 4">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding SourceImagemListVagas}" IsVisible="{Binding MostraImagem}" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="96" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding SourceCheckVagaCandidatada}" IsVisible="{Binding MostraCheckCandidatada}" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Funcao}" FontSize="24" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="0.87" Margin="0"/>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,4,0,0" IsVisible="{Binding MostraEmpresa}">
                                    <Label Text="Empresa:" FontAttributes="Bold"  FontSize="14" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="0.54"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding EmpresaResumida}" FontSize="14" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="0.54"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,4,0,0">
                                    <Label Text="Salário:" FontAttributes="Bold"  FontSize="14" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="0.54"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Salario}" FontSize="14" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="0.54"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,4">
                                    <Label Text="Localização:" FontAttributes="Bold"  FontSize="14" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="0.54"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding CidadeEstado}" FontSize="14" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="0.54"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding DescricaoResumida}" FontSize="14" TextColor="#000000" Opacity="0.54" Margin="0" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Não edite a pergunta pra colocar a solução. Se for o caso, poste uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado: Tirei o ScrollView e utilizei somente o scroll integrado do ListView. Coloquei `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` no ListView. Funcionou em todas as resoluções.

Answer (score 0):

Seu ScrollView está dentro do StackLayout, sendo assim pode ser que, como esse aparelho tenha a resolução baixa, os primeiros itens ocupem todo o espaço disponivel, não aparecendo assim o ScrollView...

eu colocaria o ScrollView e os outros dentro dele.